# $V(fg) = V(f) \cap V(g)$ is true as fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f, g$ be relatively prime irreducible polynomials in $k[X, Y].$ Denote $V(f)$ as the points that let $f$ go to zero (algebraic sets). In class we were trying to prove that $V(f) \cap V(g)$ is a finite set of points. In my lecture notes I had crossed out the comma in $V(f, g) = V(f) \cap V(g)$ to write $V(fg) = V(f) \cap V(g).$ Then I wrote down on the side that $V(fg) = V(f, g)$ is true as fields. Did I write down nonsense?

Clearly $V(fg) = V(f) \cup V(g).$ So how can we have the equality?

Comment: $f,g$ relatively prime means $(f,g) = (1)$ and $V(f,g) = \emptyset$. $V(fg) = V((f)\cap (g)) =V(f) \cup V(g)$ and $V((f,g)) = V(f) \cap V(g)$. About "as field"  : the coordinate ring $k[x,y]/(f)$ is an integral domain (so it makes sense to look at the function field) means $(f)$ is a  prime ideal, which is stronger than just $f$ being irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

$f,g$ are irreducible, and relatively prime, so share no factor
$$V(fg)=\{x\in\Bbb{A}^2\mid (fg)(x)=0\},$$
so either $f$ vanishes, or $g$ vanishes. Consider a counterexample to what you wrote: Let $K$ be a field and take $(x-1),(y-2)\in K[x,y]$:

$$V((x-1)(y-2))=\{(1,b)\mid b\in K\}\cup\{(a,2)\mid a\in K\}\ne V((x-1))\cap V((y-2))=\{(1,2)\}=V(x-1,y-2)$$

---

About the other claim, you are taking two irreducible polynomials, and you are finding their zero sets in a two dimensional space. If you are over an algebraically closed field, they'll be codimension $1$, so one dimensional. If they intersect, and are coprime, they must intersect on some dimension $0$ object.